# Python - PyCharm WebScraping - ERROR Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, pycharm, runtime-error

Can you help with this Project. My code is right but my for loop break in the second iteration, it should be 10 iterations. I try different options to solve this issue but none solve the problem.

```
import time
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl


class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def main():
    A = [
        [1, "http://www.cambi.pe/", "soup.find_all('strong')[0].text", "soup.find_all('strong')[1].text"],
        [2, "https://www.rhaak.com/", "soup.find('label', {'id':'idFormPrincipal:j_idt20'}).text",
         "soup.find('label', {'id':'idFormPrincipal:j_idt17'}).text"],
        [3, "https://www.midpointfx.com/", "soup.find_all('span',{'style':'color:#FFFFFF;'})[4].text",
         "soup.find_all('span',{'style':'color:#FFFFFF;'})[5].text"],
        [4, "https://kambista.com/", "soup.find('strong',{'id':'valcompra'}).text",
         "soup.find('strong',{'id':'valventa'}).text"],
        [5, "https://www.cambiox.pe/", "soup.find_all('span',{'class':'bold'})[1].text[8:13]",
         "soup.find_all('span',{'class':'bold'})[1].text[-5:]"],
        [6, "https://www.chasquidolar.com/",
         "soup.find('div',{'class':'preciosHome','id':'preciosHome'}).text.strip()[13:18]",
         "soup.find('div',{'class':'preciosHome','id':'preciosHome'}).text.strip()[-5:]"],
        [7, "https://www.teloscambio.com/index.php", "soup.find('span',{'id':'compra'}).text",
         "soup.find('span',{'id':'venta'}).text"],
        [8, "https://www.assessorperu.com/", "soup.find_all('span')[11].text", "soup.find_all('span')[16].text"],
        [9, "https://www.acomo.com.pe/", "soup.find('span',{'id':'current_bid'}).text[3:9]",
         "soup.find('span',{'id':'current_bid'}).text[-6:]"],
        [10, "https://www.cyberchange.pe/", "soup.find('span',{'id':'fxrate_buy_text'}).text",
         "soup.find('span',{'id':'fxrate_sell_text'}).text"]

    ]

    for elem in A:
        page = Page(elem[1])
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
        compra = eval(elem[2])
        venta = eval(elem[3])
        print(compra, venta, sep="-")

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

My code only does two iterations and then break. It should be 10 iterations
My output is:

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Users/OK/PycharmProjects/Prueba/PrimerPrograma.py
Load finished
3.536-3.556
Load finished
3.553-3.572

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

One example of the answer is:

```
Load finished
3.536-3.556
Load finished
3.553-3.572
Load finished
3.534-3.540
Load finished
3.551-3.572
Load finished
3.526-3.576
Load finished
3.513-3.592
Load finished
3.521-3.512
Load finished
3.522-3.575
Load finished
3.511-3.519
Load finished
3.503-3.574
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BAtX.jpg)

My characteristics are:

Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:01:55) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you provide the full error log and expected outcome?

Comment: When I run the code only give 2 results , it could be 10 results `Load finished hola chao 14/09/20-23:45:35-3.550-3.570 Load finished hola chao 14/09/20-23:45:40-3.553-3.572 Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` @TheGrandJ

Comment: First please [edit] it into your question. But secondly are you sure that is an error? I've never used pycharm but i don't see any big glaring error words there. Just that it finished what it was doing and exited with a code. That might just be the success code. So could you please list the full expected result and [edit] it into the question? This is to help us get you the correct results.

Comment: @TheGrandJ I did your recommendations. The code is a web scraping to 10 different websites to obtain prices about buy and sell dollars.

Comment: Hopefully someone comes to help. **The only other two things i can think of is either A that maybe the self.quit.app as part of Callable is causing an early break? Or B maybe the third site has something to prevent scraping of prices?** But again I know nothing about pycharm or webscrapping so don't take my word for it. I'm just trying to understand and help.